# Debian is installing to USB instead of HD?

Tags: partitioning, installation, debian

I am trying to install Debian onto an old PC to practice some Linux sysadmin stuff but it continually install onto the USB instead of my hard drive. I have tried the guided and manual partitioning where it explicitly says to not use the USB at all. Anyways, I'm decently familiar with Linux but this is stumping me.

The PC I'm using is a HP Media Center m7000, 80GB

Comment: p.s. I am using the Stable_NetInstall through UNetBootin